# LinearGradiant SVG Animation looks incorrect in Firefox

Tags: html, svg

I'm working with the following SVG animation that fills the house from bottom to top. It works just fine in Chrome, Safari and Internet Explorer, but doesn't work correctly in Firefox. If you pull up the snippet in Firefox you'll see that it doesn't play correctly.

```css
.house-container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px
}
```

```html
<div class="house-container">
   <svg viewBox="0 0 30 30" version="1.1" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <g
     id="Dashboard"
     stroke="none"
     stroke-width="1"
     fill="none"
     fillRule="evenodd"
     >
     <linearGradient id="house-1" x2="1" y2="4">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#ddd" />
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#ddd">
           <animate
              id="house-1"
              attributeName="offset"
              to="100%"
              dur="0.5s"
              begin="0s"
              fill="freeze"
              />
        </stop>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#10004c">
           <animate
              id="house-1"
              attributeName="offset"
              to="100%"
              dur="0.5s"
              begin="0s"
              fill="freeze"
              />
        </stop>
     </linearGradient>
     <g
        transform="translate(-1161.000000, -558.000000)"
        fill="url(#house-1)"
        >
        <g transform="translate(437.000000, 475.000000)">
           <g id="houses" transform="translate(340.000000, 83.000000)">
              <g id="house" transform="translate(384.000000, 0.000000)">
                 <polygon
                    id="Path"
                    points="21 6.66002593 21 3 25 3 25 11.1000432 30 16.6500648 25.3846154 16.6500648 25.3846154 30 4.61538462 30 4.62306431 16.6500648 0 16.6500648 15 0"
                    />
              </g>
           </g>
        </g>
     </g>
  </g>
   </svg>
</div>
```

**Gif of what it looks like in Firefox:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFGkd.jpg

I've read that Firefox has issues with SVG's, but all of my attempts to solve the animation issue have been in vein. Is there something obvious like a property I'm missing?

Comment: a) you have multiple elements with the same id value (that's invalid) b) what are you trying to achieve with  x2="1" y2="4". Those are very strange values, what do you want the animation to look like?

Comment: I want the animation to look exactly like it does in Firefox as it does in Chrome. It Firefox it behaves slightly strange.

Comment: It goes up non-horizontally (if you slow it down you'll see that). That odd angle is exactly what you want is it?

Comment: Ideally it would fill from bottom to top, but in Firefox it doesn't even do that. I'll update the post with a gif. The issue is more to do with how it doesn't look like it's even playing in Firefox at all, but it looks normal in all other browsers.

Comment: starting grey and finishing purple or the other way round?

Comment: It should finish as purple, in Firefox it finishes as grey.

Comment: Note that, given your markup, I believe Firefox's rendering is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

I've removed the duplicated ids, corrected the x1, y1, x2 and y2 values and swappd the colours round (I could have swapped the animation so it went to 0% instead I suppose).

```css
.house-container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px
}
```

```html
<div class="house-container">
   <svg viewBox="0 0 30 30" version="1.1" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <g
     id="Dashboard"
     stroke="none"
     stroke-width="1"
     fill="none"
     fillRule="evenodd"
     >
     <linearGradient id="house-1" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#ddd" />
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#ddd">
           <animate
              attributeName="offset"
              to="0%"
              dur="0.5s"
              begin="0s"
              fill="freeze"
              />
        </stop>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#10004c">
           <animate
              attributeName="offset"
              to="0%"
              dur="0.5s"
              begin="0s"
              fill="freeze"
              />
        </stop>
     </linearGradient>
     <g
        transform="translate(-1161.000000, -558.000000)"
        fill="url(#house-1)"
        >
        <g transform="translate(437.000000, 475.000000)">
           <g id="houses" transform="translate(340.000000, 83.000000)">
              <g id="house" transform="translate(384.000000, 0.000000)">
                 <polygon
                    id="Path"
                    points="21 6.66002593 21 3 25 3 25 11.1000432 30 16.6500648 25.3846154 16.6500648 25.3846154 30 4.61538462 30 4.62306431 16.6500648 0 16.6500648 15 0"
                    />
              </g>
           </g>
        </g>
     </g>
  </g>
   </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: This works in Firefox now, but no longer works in Chrome :(

Comment: @JamesIves how about now, I tried this alternative on Safari so presumably Chrome is likely to work too. Chrome/Safari's failure on my previous version is a bug in their implementation.